# DB design relation - product, category, attribute

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have 2 tables:

- products (id,name,category_id)
- categories (id,name)

I want to add third with products attributes, but attributes are specified by category. So it will be like this?

- attributes (id,name)
- attribute_product (attribute_id,product_id,value)
- attribute_category (attribute_id,category_id)

Comment: The question is confusing, try to create a model with http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 3):

Assumptions made from your question:

- a Product can have 1 and only 1 category
- you said attributes are specified by category

So, link the attributes to the category.  A Product of category X will inherit the attributes automatically.

[image]

However, this forces the value as well as the attribute.  So all products get the same attribute value (ex. all products in the Cagetory Clothes would be the same color!)  So, you want attribute *values* to be different from Product to Product in the same category:

[image]

This way, the *attribute's name* (it's existence if you want) is linked to a category, and the *value* is linked to an object.  I assumed that you want multiple attributes per object, and 1 category per attribute.

Ex:

- Category: Clothes
- Product: Shirts
- Attributes of Clotes: size and color
- Value of attributes: L and blue

So, all this to say that your initial idea was good (!).

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 "entiities" (so far) -- Products, Categories, Attributes.  These are tables.

There are essentially two "relationships" you can have:  "one-to-many" and "many-to-many".  The former just needs an `id` in one table to link to the other.  The latter needs an extra table with pairs of `ids`.

Decide what relationships you have between your entities.

Job done.